# How many custom tabs we can create in facebook page?

Tags: facebook

We have a facebook page.in which we have added a Static FBML App "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878".We have added 10 new tabs.Now we want to add more tabs,but we are not able to add more FBML tab.Its not giving an option to add more tab.
Please suggest us to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBML has closed by facebook,Now if you want to add facebook tab need to maken an app & install it on your page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've heard 10 is the max number of tabs you could have for a page. I've never had any pages with that many tabs though.

There's no straight forward way to solve this. You either need to create a new page, or combine your tabs.

-Roozbeh

Comment: We have seen some pages with more than 10 tabs.It means its possible.

Comment: Do the default tabs (Photos, Wall, etc.) count towards that 10?

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit but after a few (10 I think) many of them will be hidden behind a 'See More' link and will get very little traffic